# Disable ESLint for webpack.config.js file on Visual Studio Code

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the `vscode-eslint` extension but I'm getting warnings for the `webpack.config.js` file itself, as shown below.

[image]

How can I disable the eslint verification for this file specifically and in my own workspace (that is, without adding an `.eslintignore` file to the repo that would affect other devs)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add these lines to the VSCode `settings.json`:

```js
"eslint.options": {
    "ignorePattern": "webpack.config.js",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a file called ".eslintignore" under your root directoy and add the file you want to ignore in it.

```
cd /path/to/project

touch .eslintignore
echo "webpack.config.js" >> .eslintignore
```